# It is possible to pass data to EventArgs without creating derived class?

Tags: c#, events

I am a bit confused. I know I can create class derived from EventArgs in order to have custom event data. But can I employ the base class EventArgs somehow? Like the mouse button click, in the subscriber method, there is always "EventArgs e" parameter. Can I create somehow the method that will pass data this way, I mean they will be passed in the base Eventargs?

Comment: If you're attempting to piggyback data on a mouse click event, not only can you not do this, it indicates there is an issue with your design.

Comment: Any chance of clarifying why this is necessarily a design problem?  Can a menu not be viewed semantically as a stack of buttons, the associated event of which allows you to ask which 'button' was actually pressed in the menu?  What design principle are you breaking by wanting to pass extra information along with a button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to just use the `EventArgs` datatype raw? Absolutely. According to MSDN:

> This class contains no event data; it is used by events that do not pass state information to an event handler when an event is raised. If the event handler requires state information, the application must derive a class from this class to hold the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx

```
    private event TestEventEventHandler TestEvent;
    private delegate void TestEventEventHandler(EventArgs e);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestEvent += TestEventHandler;
        if (TestEvent != null)
        {
            TestEvent(new EventArgs());
        }
    }
    private void TestEventHandler(EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("hi");
    }
```

*Should you ever do it?* Not for any reason I can think if. If you want to create your own clicks you can just instantiate the `MouseEventArgs` on your own, too:

```
MouseEventArgs m = new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 1, 42, 42, 1);
```

Comment: You can also use EventArgs.Empty
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty.aspx

Comment: Is it a typo? `TestEventEventHandler`. There are two Event words. But in the code. You used `TestEventHandler`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the EventArgs class through the Generic Types approach. In this sample, i will use the Rect class with as return type:

```
public EventHandler<Rect> SizeRectChanged;
```

Raising the event:

```
if(SizeRectChanged != null){
   Rect r = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
   SizeRectChanged(this,r);
}
```

Listening the event:

```
anyElement.SizeRectChanged += OnSizeRectChanged;

public void OnSizeRectChanged(object sender, Rect e){
    //TODO abything using the Rect class
    e.Left = e.Top = e.Width = e.Height = 50;
}
```

So, don't need to create new events classes or delegates, simply create a EventHandler passing the specific type T.

Comment: This looks wrong.  The [MSDN website example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows that Rect or TEventArg has to inherit from EventArgs.  Unless there is something I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Thomas, I found this confusing too.  But jupi's suggestion worked for me.

Comment: Wow... wish I had known this a long time ago.  I always assumed that when you declared EventHandler<T>, that T must derive from EventArgs.  So for example if I needed to send a string with my event, I would make a new class StringEventArgs which subclassed from EventArgs.  The MSDN doc linked to by Thomas Lann certainly does say "Its second parameter is derived from type EventArgs and holds the event data" which would imply to most readers that you cannot use any arbitrary class.  But the compiler seems not to mind a EventHandler<string> and this works entirely fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: In Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, this raises an error: Error CS0315 The type 'float' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. There is no boxing conversion from 'float' to 'System.EventArgs'.

Answer (score 10):

Nope. The EventArgs base class is just a way to allow for some standard event delegate types. Ultimately, to pass data to a handler, you'll need to subclass EventArgs. You could use the sender arg instead, but that should really be the object that fired the event.

Comment: Thumbs up for directing me to the `sender` arg, that's exactly what I needed to communicate to the handler